# How does Temple Run 2 measure "Life-Time" Coins?

Tags: temple-run-2

I am playing a lot of Temple Run 2, but one thing is bothering me about the game. The following picture is a screenshot of my objectives and my "Midas Touch" green progress bar isn't filling up at all! But my Gold Miner is almost finished (I have about 400,000 coins).

[image]

Could this be a bug? One thing I've been wondering about is I heavily rely on the "Coin" Powerup, do coins earned by the powerup count towards these objectives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was frustrated with the same issue. I believe that the *lifetime coins* challenges do not start counting until after the objective is activated (which could be a bug). You probably activated Gold Miner first, collected nearly 400k coins, and then completed a separate challenge that then activated Midas Touch. From that point all coins collected applied to both Midas Touch and Gold Miner, but because Gold Miner was open first, it has more progress. And, of course, the Midas Touch progress bar is going to fill half as fast as Gold Miner's.

I actually stopped playing after I noticed this. Even though they decreased the +2 Gem Powerup to level 9, it will just take too long to complete the lifetime challenges. If it had been counting my true lifetime progress, they would have been completed already.

Comment: You are right about unlocking the 1 mil objective after a considerable amount of time had passed (and coins collected) since I unlocked the 500,000 one. So perhaps you're assumptions are correct. A bit disappointing because I have lots of coins to collect lol. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Actually there was a bug with lifetime coins/distance when Temple Run 2 launched - they were resetting every time you started a new game, you could see this from the stats in the options. The number for the objective seems to be tracked separately, and starts from whatever number your lifetime coins/distance is at when you get the objective. I think the problem is fixed now, do you have the latest version of the game? I can't test this any more because I'd cleared those objectives by the time the patch came out.

Comment: I think I have the most recent version. I have 1.0.1. I am not detecting another patch. I just noticed that my lifetime coins shown in stats seems to have dropped considerably. And is actually much less than what I have in my bank. That can't be right.

Comment: I have 1.0.1 version also, no update in the App Store yet.