# Life time coins temple run 2

Tags: temple-run-2

I have taken more coins to complete Midas touch objective. But in game it is showing that I have not completed. What should I do ?

Comment: Hello, I asked a similar question last week, this might be of some help: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107027/how-does-temple-run-2-measure-life-time-coins Seems like it maybe a bug